# NodeJs Express: Cannot post a request

Tags: node.js, express

I'm not able to post a request. I ensured that I have the urlencoded set to false.

When I try to post with parameters, I end up with "Cannot GET ....." in the webpage.

Not sure why that is.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/task-create/title/:title/description/:description/start/:start/end/:end/priority/:priority/category/:category/status/:status", async (req, res) => {

  const task = new Task(
    { 
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
      start: req.body.start,
      end: req.body.end,
      priority: req.body.priority,
      category: req.body.category,
      status: req.body.status
    });

  await task.save().then(() => console.log("Task created"));

  res.send("Task created \n");
});
```

Comment: I think the await is causing issues

Comment: This is a bit of a very long route definition.  What exact URL are you using that you want to match this route with?  From the look of your code, I think you're confused about how a post works and where the data comes.  It does NOT come from the URL with all the parameters you define in this URL.  It comes form the body.  I suspect your post is NOT matching this route because this route definition is misunderstood.

Comment: I removed the await and async, still the same problem

Comment: @jfriend00, where does the data come from for a post request?

Comment: Why are you getting a "Cannot GET ..." error message on a POST?  Something isn't correct there.

Comment: The data is in the body and you can access it like `req.body.title` (if you have the right middleware to parse the body).  But, it should NOT be in the URL and your route requires the data to be in both which is just wrong.  What is the URL you are posting to?

Comment: I want to have some parameters to post. Lets say the url is /task-create

Comment: Please show the client code that makes the post.  I've asked you several times what URL you're posting to and you aren't answering me.  It seems likely that your route definition is wrong and doesn't match the URL you're posting to and that's why the route doesn't work.  But, if you're not going to answer my questions, I can't help any further.

Comment: I haven't have a client code yet.

I'm going to test with some constants:

const task = new Task(
    { 
      title: "title",
      description: "description",
      start: "start",
      end: "end",
      priority: "priority",
      category: "category",
      status: "status"
    });

If I replace the task from above with this blob, this does not work either

Comment: what do you mean by `When I try to post with parameters, I end up with "Cannot GET ....." in the webpage.` ? are you redirecting to this URL in browser?

Comment: @DanCode If you don't have client code, how do you call this route with POST method?

Comment: @Guillaume I'm trying to test it with some constants

Comment: How are you testing? using postman or any tool? or directly in browser?\

Comment: Last and final time I will ask.  What URL are you posting to?

Comment: @jfriend, I don't have any client code yet. So no url at this moment. I will take the advice to use postman to test it

Comment: If there's no URL, then how are you "posting with parameters" like your question says?  You post to a URL.  Your question makes no sense at all now as I have no idea at all what you're doing or where your error comes from.  Your question does not currently make sense.  You claim to be doing something that you are not doing.  I can also tell you that your route definition is wrong, but you apparently haven't even gotten that far yet.

Comment: @jfriend00, I changed my question, look in the comments.

Comment: It occurs to me that maybe you think `app.post(...)` should actually run that request handler?  If that's what you're thinking, that isn't at all what it does.  It registers a route on your web server that a client can then send a request to and if and only if the path on the incoming request matches your route definition, will it then run that request handler.  Because you have all sorts of stuff in the route definition string, there's no way that's ever going to match a real world path either.

Comment: If you intend to change your question, then use the "edit" button to actually edit your question.  You don't change a question in the comments.  Your question still say ***When I try to post with parameters, I end up with "Cannot GET ....." in the webpage.*** which is apparently not what you're doing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use a rest client to test that endpoint and assign it the post method, not directly from the browser. You can use [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) or [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).